# g++ linking issues: undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, linker, g++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I used CMake and Visual C++ to build the HyDE library.  Then, still in VC++, I was able to successfully create code and build an executable that links into HyDE.lib and the HyDE header files.

I then discovered that in order to work with others at my company, it would be preferable to develop in Eclipse CDT.  Knowing very little about Eclipse CDT, I created a default hello world project, deleted the code and then dumped in all of my code into the src folder.  Then I attempted to change the includes and lib path and libs to mirror what had worked in VC++.  At this point everything seems to compile, but I get an error in linking:

> /cygdrive/c/EclipseWorkspace/425HyDE/Debug/../src/FS5HyDE.cpp:16: undefined reference to `HyDEAPI::HyDE::HyDE(HyDESystemModel::SystemModel*, bool)'

(There are many more errors like this, all referring to HyDE methods.)  Here is what is being run at the command line:

> g++ -L"C:\Progra~1\boost\boost_1_42\lib" -L"C:\EclipseWorkspace\HyDE" -o"425HyDE.exe"  ./src/Adapter_FS5HyDE.o ./src/EPSCommands.o ./src/EPSCurrentSensor.o ./src/EPSFault.o ./src/FS5HyDE.o ./src/HyDEObservation.o ./src/MCDH.o ./src/MCDH_Module.o ./src/PDBComponent.o ./src/PowerSystem.o ./src/Program.o ./src/SSPCComponent.o ./src/Telemetry.o ./src/TelemetryReport.o   -l:libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_42.lib -lHyDE

This is definitely not a library ordering problem because I've the other ordering as well (there are only two).  Is it possible that there is a problem with compiling HyDE.lib in VC++ (which uses a Windows compiler) and compiling my program with g++?  Could there be a problem in the way that Eclipse CDT is autogen'ing the makefiles?  Any other ideas?

(Note: there appear to be plenty of others questions on SO with similar problems, but after reading through them I have yet to find one that addresses my problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Since the HyDE library was compiled with the Visual Studios compiler and I'm attempting to build the code that links to it with the Cygwin toolchain the two compilers use different name mangling schemes so that the latter linker can not find the expected symbols in the HyDE library.  The only solution that I've found is to recompile the HyDE library with the Cygwin toolchain *or* compile the new code with whatever compiler Visual Studios is using. (grumble grumble)

Answer (score 1):

Classic missing symbol error. Which source file defines:

`HyDEAPI::HyDE::HyDE(HyDESystemModel::SystemModel*, bool)'` ?

Was this file added to the compilation? Can you spot it on the command line you pasted?

If this symbol belongs to an external library, after adding the directory path with `-L` , you could add the name of the specific library you want to link with your program using `-l`.

I'm going to suggest that you try to add to the compilation command the directory path to HyDE.lib, followed immediately by the library name, like this:

```
 -L"C:\path_to_hyde_library" -l:HyDE.lib
```

and then tell us what happened.

Comment: -L"C:\EclipseWorkspace\HyDE" and -lHyDE in the above post *should* do what you say.  I've also tried -l:HyDE.lib.  Same result.

Comment: Were you able to link on the command line - without eclipse. Does the linking work with whatever the command line you used? One more thing you can try is -l"complete library path including lib name"

Comment: @Gandahar I am not able to link on the command line using the same command.  Also using -l"full path" doesn't work.  Using -l"full cygwin path" doesn't work.

Comment: I'm building 425HyDE.exe and linking to HyDE.lib

Answer (score 0):

`./src/FS5HyDE.o` and `./src/HyDEObservation.o` should be the latest parameter if other *object files (*.o files)* **need** them, it means that the most needed `object files` should be appeared as last as possible in the parameters list.