# Strange issue with MinGW make command (with muParser)?

Tags: command-line, makefile, mingw

I'm having the strangest issue while trying to build and install muParser on my windows machine. As suggested by the installation guide, I just cd into the build folder, and run

```
make -f makefile.mingw
```

This should be all well and good standard procedure. However, I can't make sense of the output from the command:

```
if not exist obj\gcc_static_rel mkdir obj\gcc_static_rel
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Chase\Desktop\muparser_v2_0_0\muparser_v2_0_0\build>
```

Now... at this point, I'm really confused. Because according to the title of the command prompt window, I'm still INSIDE the make command. So, I type "exit" at the "prompt"

```
g++ -c -o obj\gcc_static_rel\muParser_lib_muParser.o -DNDEBUG -O2     -D_WIN32 -     I..\include   -MTobj\gcc_static_rel\muParser_lib_muParser.o -  MFobj\gcc_static_rel\muParser_lib_muParser.o.d -MD -MP ../src/muParser.cpp
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Chase\Desktop\muparser_v2_0_0\muparser_v2_0_0\build>
```

The command appears to "step" through it's next function. I continue to type exit at the "prompt" and the command appears to continue stepping until it's done. However, after exiting completely, I can't see any results and it appears nothing's actually been done.

Also, this doesn't have anything to do with the command prompt. I even wrote a python script to cd into the directory and call make, and the output still displayed a windows-style command prompt - complete with the copyright Microsoft line etc., and waited for an input. I typed exit the same way until the process exited back to python.

Now, I might be going insane, but I'm really confused. Asking on the forums yielded no help, the only response is that "the windows build should be working."

Does anyone know what's going on???

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the muParser package and tried to build it. I got the same strange behaviour from make as you did. Then I realised I only had MSYS-make installed, not MinGW-make (the first one is intended for use in the MSYS shell, the second one for use in the Windows cmd shell).
Unfortunately, installing and using mingw32-make gave a different error, but googling that lead me to [this page](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/print-thread/593750), where it was suggested to rename sh.exe in the MSYS directory. After doing that, running `mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw` succesfully built (the static version of) the library.

The other method you and shellter are using of running `./configure; make` in the MSYS shell, also fails to build the example for me. It does build the dll version of the library in this case, instead of the static version; perhaps this is why the example fails to build.

Comment: After 5 years since it has been posted, thank you. I had sh.exe somewhere in the path. Renaming it before building solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

(You might want to add a tag for 'make' or 'gmake', that should boost the number of eyes looking at your problem).

Looking at the makefile.mingw, I'm surprised to see statements like '-if not exist ..', that is .bat file syntax.

I ran `./configure ; make` and it got past the error messages you mention, but I'm seeing a bunch of error messages like `undefined reference to mu::ParserError:` , so I'm probably missing libraries to make it work completely. I'll have to leave it at that, and hope that it helps you. Note that I didn't use `make -f makefile.mingw`. After using `configure`, `make`  just picked up the newly created Makefile, and it worked (excepting the library problems ;-)

(When you say forums, did you mean the mingw forums? If not, try looking around [here](http://old.nabble.com/MinGW-f1890.html). The search functionality is pretty good.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've done the same thing and am also seeing issue with undefined references.... I don't know what to think here...

Comment: For me it is the example programs that are failing with undefined references. I think muParser is now correct, but I don't know how to test it. It may be working now. Do you need the examples? See further edit of answer. Good luck.

Comment: Nothing wrong with lib*.dll.a. It's a common naming scheme for the import library accompanying a dll.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'm removing my mention of this issue from my response.

Comment: @Erictous is on the right track. The best I can offer is check out this info on 'classic missing symbol error' here on S.O. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515770/g-linking-issues-undefined-reference-to-functions/3515822#3515822 Sorry to say, but because most developers don't have to deal with these issues on a regular basis, it can take hours (or more) to figure out these problems unless you get some expert help. Good luck.